# Monitoring usage for nvidia switchable graphics card without keeping it awake

Tags: linux, nvidia, optimus, hybrid-graphics

I am attempting to build a graphics card monitor (temp, mem%, utilization, etc) for a system with switchable graphics on Linux.

TLDR: Because I have an Ampere dGPU with runtime D3 (RTD3), the monitor somehow needs to figure out when the dGPU is being "used" by something else, and not query it otherwise to prevent it from waking up. Defining what "used" really means is the current difficulty.

##### background

In the past when I was using optimus-manager, this was relatively easy to do with something like `nvidia-settings -t -q UsedDedicatedGPUmemory -q ...` in a loop that only ran when the GPU was detected to be on according to `cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/runtime_status`.

However, now I have a fancy new laptop with an Nvidia Ampere dGPU which supports runtime D3 power management, and therefore I don't need to use optimus-manager to force my dGPU on/off. I can verify that the dGPU is normally off via the above sysfs command, and then turns on for about 15 seconds after running something like `prime-run glxinfo | grep -i opengl` before turning off again.

The problem now is that if I try to make a system monitor with `nvidia-settings` (or `nvidia-smi`) in a loop to query the dGPU for runtime information, the dGPU will automatically turn on. I can use the value of `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/runtime_status` to noop the query loop when the dGPU is suspended, but then once the dGPU wakes up and my monitor starts querying it won't go back to sleep (because each query keeps it awake).

##### ideas I've explored

I've found elsewhere that others have used the `/dev/nvidia*` files and `nvidia-smi` to determine which processes are "using" the dGPU. In my case at idle (ie dGPU is suspended) and with `nvidia-settings` open:

```
> sudo lsof /dev/nvidia*
COMMAND     PID                USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nvidia-pe   796 nvidia-persistenced    4u   CHR 195,255      0t0  765 /dev/nvidiactl
nvidia-pe   796 nvidia-persistenced    5u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
nvidia-pe   796 nvidia-persistenced    6u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
nvidia-pe   796 nvidia-persistenced    7u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
nvidia-pe   796 nvidia-persistenced    8u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root  mem    CHR   195,0           772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root  mem    CHR 195,255           765 /dev/nvidiactl
Xorg       1105                root    9u   CHR 195,255      0t0  765 /dev/nvidiactl
Xorg       1105                root   13u   CHR 195,255      0t0  765 /dev/nvidiactl
Xorg       1105                root   22u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root   23u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root   24u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root   29u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root   30u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root   33u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root   34u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root   35u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root   44u   CHR 195,254      0t0  774 /dev/nvidia-modeset
Xorg       1105                root   59u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
Xorg       1105                root   60u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
nvidia-se 84896               ndwar    6u   CHR 195,255      0t0  765 /dev/nvidiactl
nvidia-se 84896               ndwar    7u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
nvidia-se 84896               ndwar    8u   CHR   510,0      0t0  766 /dev/nvidia-uvm
nvidia-se 84896               ndwar   10u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
nvidia-se 84896               ndwar   11u   CHR   195,0      0t0  772 /dev/nvidia0
```

And if I ask nvidia directly which processes are using the card (this will obviously wake it up briefly):

```
> nvidia-smi pmon -c 1
# gpu         pid  type    sm    mem    enc    dec    command
# Idx           #   C/G     %      %      %      %    name
    0       1105     G      -      -      -      -    Xorg
```

I'm a bit confused by what this all means because I can force the dGPU to stay on by going to the "Thermal Settings" page in `nvidia-settings`; however, the outputs above don't change (eg nvidia-smi doesn't say `nvidia-settings` is "using" the dGPU). Furthermore, Xorg is always running, yet the dGPU is suspended unless I open another application to specifically use the dGPU.

##### system info

OS: arch linux

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107GLM [RTX A1000 6GB Laptop GPU] (rev a1)
```

```
> cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Runtime D3 status:          Enabled (fine-grained)
Video Memory:               Off

GPU Hardware Support:
 Video Memory Self Refresh: Supported
 Video Memory Off:          Supported
```

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (RPL-P)
```

```
prime-run glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA RTX A1000 6GB Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
```